# how to execute code after yylex(); command

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I have a simple flex source code which skips the comments in `/* */` and should get the count of comments found:

```
%{
  int in_comment = 0;
  int count = 0;
%}

%%
\/\* { in_comment = 1; count++; }
\*\/ { in_comment = 0; }
.    { if (!in_comment) ECHO; }
%%

int main(void)
{
  yylex();
  printf("Comments found %d\n", count); // never executed
  return 0;
}
```

First half works fine - it really skips the comments, but they are not counted... what can I do to execute `printf` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it myself. So I copied your source code to "x.l" and did a `make x`
ld then complained about the missing yywrap() function. After adding

```
%option noyywrap
```

The compile succeeded and a test showed:

```
ronald@cheetah:~/tmp$ ./x < cribbage.c
... lots of output ...
Comments found 15
```

**UPDATE:**

If the text is not loaded from a file (just `./x`), you have to end your manual input by `CTRL + D`

Comment: Thank you... in my case, everything is compiled without warnings or errors, but Comments found is missing :(

Comment: does your program return in the first place? Or does it hang? In case of the latter, the lexer wants more input (which is controlled by the yywrap() function). So please try my suggestion

Comment: I've tried it but without success. It's printing the sentences without comments as I wanted, no hang, everything seems to be ok, but count is not printed

Comment: weird... how do you compile and link? OS? flex version? (sorry about that many questions, but now we'll have to dig deeper)

Comment: Omg, i've found it! When I'm reading text from file (`./test < file.txt`), it works perfectly. When I run it just by `./test` and writing text manually, it doesn't work.. But i don't know why now

Comment: hm, do you end your input with a "ctrl-D"?

Comment: NO :-) It would be the whole problem :-))) Thank you very much!