# How to end input in lex when executing on CMD win7

Tags: c, lex

[how to execute code after yylex(); command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21233024/7101158)

I have the same problem as the above question, not able to execute anything below the yylex()

```
    %{
       #include<stdio.h>
       int vowel=0;
       int cons=0;
    %}
    %%
   "a"|"e"|"i"|"o"|"u"|"A"|"E"|"I"|"O"|"U" {printf("is a VOWEL");vowel++;}
    [a-zA-z] {printf("Is a Consonant");cons++;}
    %%
  int yywrap()
  {
   return 1;
  }
  main()
  {
   printf("Enter String\n");
  yylex();
   printf("vowel=%d and Consonent=%d",vowel,cons);//how to execute this statement?
    }
```

I am on win7 and the answer says to end your input using Ctrl+d(tried does not work in CMD).

So how to end your input which enables the next statement to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how to end your input which enables the next statement to execute?

`yylex()` will continue to wait on and process input until it sees end-of-file *or* it executes an action that performs an explicit `return`.

The Windows analog of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, so you could try that, but it would be much better to configure the lexer with a rule that makes it return.  For example, if you only need to lex a single line of input (per call), then you might make it return when it reads a newline.  Do note, however, that `yylex()` may buffer input characters, which can cause some unprocessed input to be lost if you attempt to read the same input file after `yylex()` returns, except by calling `yylex()` itself again.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> alternative of Ubuntu in Windows:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>